# Where is everything saved when I "try Ubuntu without installing?"

Tags: ram, live-environment

The reason I ask is because I ran out of space each time Steam tried to unpack, and none of my drives or devices are full.

Comment: As Mseqade states: "in memory". But the "try out Ubuntu" means trying out Ubuntu not trying out steam. For that I suggest installing Ubuntu 1st. The idea of the "try" feature is to check if all hardware works (or at least the important parts) and Ubuntu is useable. Beside that it can be used as a diagnostic tool but that is about it ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's stored in memory and it will be deleted when you reboot the computer. So if you have a low amount of RAM it's very likely that you run out of space quickly.

Comment: I believe that also swap space on disk is used when available; although this can happen just when a swap partition exist (which is unlikely if no distributions have been previously installed).